Liquid section code is not being recognized as liquid in Visual Studio Code
I am getting this error "at-rule or selector expected" in VS Code because this section of my code (see Image 1) is not being recognized as liquid:

Visual Studio Code should recognize this part like this in white (See image 2), but for some reason I can't make this section for VS Code to be seen as liquid language

Initially when I made the repo I did not have this error but I made a little change and now it does not recognize it, even though I put the original code, I'd appreciate your help
This is the complete html code:
---
layout: compress
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% if site.analytics-google %}
        {% include analytics-google.html %}
    {% endif %}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name=author content="{{ site.title }}">
    {% seo %}
    {% include favicon.html %}
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="{{ site.title }}" href="{{ site.url }}{{ "/feed.xml" }}" />
    <style>
        {% if site.dark-theme == "auto" %}
            {% capture scss_sheet %}
                {% include style.scss %}
                @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
                    {% include style-dark.scss %}
                }
            {% endcapture %}
        {% elsif site.dark-theme %}
            {% capture scss_sheet %}{% include style-dark.scss %}{% endcapture %}
        {% else %}
            {% capture scss_sheet %}{% include style.scss %}{% endcapture %}
        {% endif %}
        {{ scss_sheet | scssify }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper-{% if site.width == "normal" %}normal{% elsif site.width == "large" %}large{% endif %}">
        {% if page.layout == "post" %}
            <div class="post">
        {% else %}
            {% if showHeader != true %}
                <div class="page {{ page.title | downcase }}">
            {% else %}
                <div class="{{ page.title | downcase }}">
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
            {{ content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

I tried to put back the original code that was working but it still does not work
I tried getting an extension for liquid and did not work.

Which extension did you try? What did not work? Did you try restarting VS? I see there is an official extension from Shopify.

Please note that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code alias VS Code are two completely different applications. I edited your post accordingly.

Hello @anupsabraham I installed "Liquid from panoply" but the codes still does not recognize me that section as correct because it thinks is is html code but it is liquid

@PeterMacej ok thanks for the observation

@robdevmx Try the extension I linked in the first comment. It is an official one from Shopify themselves.

@anupsabraham I tried with the shopify extension but I still get the error
